# Hide vertex colors in vertex painting view

Tags: vertex-colors

Simply put, I struggle with the same problem found on this unanswered question:
[Hide Vertex Colors while painting](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/143593/hide-vertex-colors-while-painting)

Is there a way to disable displaying vertex colors while in vertex color painting mode?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In vertex paint mode, simply change the rendering to either look dev or rendered:

[image]

Comment: Thank you! I was still using Blender 2.8 which displayed the vertex colors in all rendering modes, updating Blender fixed the problem for me.